# Proof that there exists a string of strictly increasing or decreasing (not necessarily consecutive) integers inside a permutation of $\Bbb{Z_n}$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a permutation of $\Bbb{Z_n}$. In other words, $A:\Bbb{Z_n} \to \Bbb{Z_n}$ is a bijection. Prove: $$\exists_{I\, \subset \, \Bbb{Z_n}}\,\vert I \vert = \lfloor \sqrt{n-1} \rfloor \, \land \, (\forall_{x,y\, \in \, I} \; (x<y)\to(A(x) < A(y)) \, \lor \, \forall_{x,y \, \in \, I} \; (x<y)\to (A(x) > A(y)))$$

Essentially, if you take the first $n$ whole numbers and consider them to be a finite sequence with no repeats, then there is a not-necessarily consecutive subsequence of length $\lfloor \sqrt{n-1} \rfloor$ of strictly increasing or decreasing values. It's a sort of "unavoidable pattern" when dealing with finite sequences of non-repeated integers. For example, take this permutation of $\Bbb{Z_{10}}: \{2, 0, 3, 6, 8, 7, 1, 9, 4, 5\}$. The set $I$, in this case, would always have cardinality of $3$ because $3 = \lfloor \sqrt{10-1} \rfloor$. $I$, for example, could be $\{0,2,4\}$ because $2 < 3 < 8$. Or the set $I$ could be $\{4, 5, 9\}$ because $8 > 7 > 5$. The proof only needs to prove the existence of one such $I$ for any permutation of $\Bbb{Z_n}$, either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. I remember this proof being an exercise in Discrete Mathematics 2 and it had something to do with the pigeonhole principle. I would love to reprove this, but I have lost my notes! Any help or any formatting tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is famously known as the [Erdos-Szekeres theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem).

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!